# Weird tab bar glitch

Tags: swift, swiftui

When I try to make a tab bar in swift I get a weird looking tab bar
[Tab Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPEJ1.png)

I don't even have a loop so how can I be showing 3 home items?
my code for my tab bar

MainView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                }
            Search()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    
                }
            AddItemsView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Add Items", systemImage: "plus")
                }
            AccountView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Account", systemImage: "person.circle")
                }
            DetailView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Test", systemImage: "square")
                }
            

            
        }
    }
}
```

I show the MainView here -

```
if viewModel.signedIn{
    VStack{
        MainView()
    }
}
```

ANY Help is Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
TabView {
        HomeView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
            }
           .tag(0)
        Search()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                
            }
            .tag(1)
        AddItemsView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Add Items", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            .tag(2)
        AccountView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Account", systemImage: "person.circle")
            }
            .tag(3)
        DetailView()
            .tabItem {
                Label("Test", systemImage: "square")
            }
            .tag(4)
     }
```

They need to be uniquely identifiable hence the `tag` items.

Comment: no luck still glitchy

Answer (score 0):

This is a full code with no glitch and a login:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showLoginView: Bool = false

        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                if showLoginView {
                    MainView()
                } else {
                    Button("Login") {
                        self.showLoginView = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
            TabView {
                HomeView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                    }
                Search()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Search", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                        
                    }
                AddItemsView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Add Items", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                AccountView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Account", systemImage: "person.circle")
                    }
                DetailView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Test", systemImage: "square")
                    }
                

                
            }
        }
    
}
    
struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
struct Search: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
    }
}

struct AddItemsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.yellow
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}
struct AccountView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.purple
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.red
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            
    }
    
}
```

Comment: still no fix, it is still glitchy and weird

Comment: try to create a new swift ui project, paste my code, and see if its still glitchy. if it still glitchy the reason may come from something else. If it is not glitchy, then the problem could come from a part of code u didn't share.

Comment: its only in this project

Comment: then the reason probably comes from a piece of code you didn't share because when I test your code in a new project, or my code, there is no glitch from what is shared on here.

Comment: but I don't have any other code relating to a tab bar?

Comment: what does your glitch look like?

Comment: my error. https://imgur.com/a/bnr8g0S

Comment: On the screenshot you gave, there is a sign out button, and on the code you shared there is no sign out button. There is a piece of code somewhere that cause the glitch. 
Search the full code and type "home" or try cmd + F and type "home" on the page to quickly locate where you repeated "home". But from the code you shared or from my solution, there is no glitch...